# Как узнать включена ли конкретная опция в конфигурации PHP

Tags: php, configure

Если воспользоваться функцией `phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL)` мы получим разные полезные данные. Можно ли из PHP как-то добраться до конкретной опции, которая находится в `Configure Command`?
Тот же вопрос, другими словами: если это возможно, то как проверить, включена ли опция `--enable-sigchild`?

```
if('--enable-sigchild')
    ...
else
    ...
```

Comment: Не думаю так как это опции для компиляции PHP через GCC. Если у вас есть php-devel, то вы можете использовать [php-config](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/configure.about.php) скрипт для проверки.

Comment: Я так понимаю ваш предложенный вариант не сможет помочь мне выяснить, на стороне клиента, использует ли он enable-sigchild?

Comment: Можно вызвать опцию и в случае неудачи перехватить ошибку

Comment: @Николай, отлично, спасибо. Просто я тоже про это подумал :) Спровоцировать ошибку и от нее отталкиваться. Поищу инфо про то, как можно понять, что enable-sigchild включена или отключена. Если кто-то уже знает, поделитесь, пожалуйста

Comment: Читали про PCNTL? https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pcntl.php

Comment: Мда, все оказалось сложнее, чем я ожидал. Для меня это совсем новая тема. Не понимаю, как связать сигналы с Configure Command, в частности с enable-sigchild. Может быть, кто-то мог бы показать на примере?

Comment: Насколько я знаю вызов сигнала сам возвращает True или false